# why daemon process terminate

Tags: linux, python-3.x, python-daemon

I use [python-daemon](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/) for my home project. But I not understand why daemon teminated after 1 day working.

this my code:

```
import requests
import time
import subprocess
import os
import lockfile
import daemon
import logging
import signal
import sys

Class MyDaemon():

def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                self.check_updates()
                time.sleep(5)
            except ConnectionError as e:
                self.log.error('Connerction Error')
                time.sleep(120)
            except (OSError, IOError) as e:
                self.log.error('I/O Error')
                time.sleep(120)
            except Exception as e:
                self.log.error('Exception: '.format(e.__class__))
                time.sleep(120)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot = MyDaemon()
    context = daemon.DaemonContext(
        working_directory=bot.path,
        umask=0o002,
        pidfile=lockfile.FileLock('/tmp/mydaemon.pid'),

    )
    # exit()
    if context.pidfile.is_locked():
        exit('daemon is running now!')

    #context.signal_map = {signal.SIGHUP: 'terminate',
    #                      signal.SIGUSR1: bot.reload_bot(),
    #                      signal.SIGTERM: bot.exit_bot(),
    #                      }

    context.files_preserve = [bot.fh.stream]  # logging

    with context:
        bot.run()
```

This privat bot for telegram. In function check_updates(self) send request and treats response for server It's func normali workink in shell(tmux on server). In function run() I catch all exceptions (at least i think so :) ) but this path not workin where i wrong?

Thank's

Comment: All daemons should log somewhere.  What do the logs say?

Comment: there is only my log file, that create logging module and his no write warning or error